# Android alarmmanager notification is not correctly working when device is rebooted

Tags: java, android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I create an android app which can show notifications after five minutes from the app launch . Popup a notification from the device reboot is a specific task of the app . I use `BroadcastReceiver`, `Service` & `AlaramManager` for the above task . This is working when device is alive . this works when the device is reebooted but the notification is generated before 5 minutes.

For an example , I planned to show this notification after each 5 minutes . Then I launched the application . Before the five minutes I restarted the device . I got a notification before the five minutes and after the device reboot .

But my expectation is , get the notification after the five minutes with device reboot .

Here are the steps which I follow to do above .

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.context=this;

        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));

    }
}
```

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Let it continue running until it is stopped.


        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
        intent = new Intent(MyService1.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyService1.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MyService1.this.getSystemService(MyService1.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000 * 60 * 5, pendingIntent);


        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private int MID = 0;

    public static boolean isCreated;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")){

            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    context).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Alaram Fired")
                    .setContentText("Events To be Performed").setSound(alarmSound)
                    .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

                    .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
            notificationManager.notify(MID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
            MID++;

        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.agent_app.mynotification">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <service android:name=".MyService"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.agent_app.mynotification.AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Have any iedas ?

Thank you .

Comment: When your Receiver runs from the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast, it's just immediately creating the `Notification`. You're not setting an alarm 5 minutes into the future there.

Comment: @MikeM. :-  If it is , how can I set an alarm for the future.

Comment: The same way you're setting it in the `Service`. Check `intent.getAction()` in `onReceive()`, and if it's the `BOOT_COMPLETED` action, set the alarm. Otherwise, issue your `Notification`.

Comment: The `Intent`'s action `String` is going to be null when it runs from the alarm, since you're using an explicit `Intent` there. You can either do a null check, or do something like `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())`.

Comment: @MikeM.: I did everything which you told me . But still gain the same result .

Comment: @MikeM. :- Now I haven't get any exception . But expected result is not coming out .

Comment: @MikeM. : - I re-correct my code and it solved exception . But still notification is showing before the estimated time .

Comment: @MikeM. :- Can you provide me a sample code ?

Comment: @MikeM. : I updated the code

Comment: It needs to be like `if(BOOT_COMPLETED) { set alarm } else { create notification }`.